# How should I download Red Hat Enterprise Linux?

Tags: rhel, download

I am aware that [Red Hat Enterprise Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) (RHEL) is not free, that is, Red Hat charges money for the support it gives for RHEL, and I am also aware of the [Fedora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29) project of Red Hat. But I want to experience RHEL in my virtual machine for practicing commands as I just started with Linux.

I want to download RHEL (not from a torrent as torrents don't work at my college) without any Red Hat support as Red Hat charges only for support and not the OS.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about downloading a particular linux distribution.  Contact the vendor instead.

Comment: It seems to me (I haven't done it) that while you may need to [register an account](https://www.redhat.com/wapps/sso/login.html?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Frhn.redhat.com%2Frhn%2Fsoftware%2Fdownloads%2FSupportedISOs.do) in order to download from Redhat, that alone does not cost anything. Have you tried?  BTW, if you just want something to run in a VM for learning basic *nix commands, it does not matter at all which linux distro you choose.  They are all identical in that sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As gena2x suggested, you can use [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS). But, you can also download the actual release candidate of RHEL 7. See:

- [RHEL 7 RC is available](http://seven.centos.org/2014/04/rhel-7-rc-is-available/)
- [Development Release: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 RC](http://distrowatch.com/?newsid=08406)* (DistroWatch.com News)
- [Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Release Candidate Now Publicly Available](http://www.redhat.com/about/news/archive/2014/4/red-hat-enterprise-linux-7-release-candidate-now-publicly-available)

Answer (score 0):

Just use CentOS. It's almost 1:1 to the RHEL. Just recompiled sources.

Comment: RHEL is still so costly to buy.I need that linux ditro in which commands work exactly the same as that in RHEL without any modification.I tried using Ubuntu instead but it requires many modifications for most of the commands.

Comment: Ubuntu is debian based. So, you should try rhel7 rc, CentOS or fedora.